# SQL Server : lock table to block other sessions trying to read the table

Tags: sql-server, locking

I need to be able to lock a table in SQL Server while doing some work. The lock needs to block other sessions from reading the table. When the work is complete the table needs to be unlocked.

In MySQL I have done this by using:

```
LOCK TABLES [table] WRITE
```

At this point other sessions will be blocked when trying read from the table, until the table is unlocked.

```
UNLOCK TABLES
```

Now the blocking will stop.

Is this possible in SQL Server?

Comment: Transactions + Isolation Levels

Comment: Technically possible? Yes. Recommend in practice - no. This really kills your system performance. Think again about *why* you really need this - you must likely don't need it at all ..

Comment: It's to ensure background jobs gets run on only one of the nodes in a clustered environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION 

    SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM TableName WITH (TABLOCKX)
  /* do your stuff here */

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

`TABLOCKX` will obtain an exclusive lock on the table and other users will not be able to read or update the data until you commit the transaction yourself.

**Edit**

Instead of doing a `SELECT *` like i suggested before, just do a `SELECT TOP 1 1` it will get an exclusive lock on the table and will not waste any time returning actual data like a `SELECT *`would do.